# Which is Better/Faster isEmpty() or isBlank()?

Tags: apex, string

There is a method that has some conditional logic and returns an empty String '' (no space) in some cases. Which method is more effective/faster to use in this case: String.isEmpty() or String.isBlank()?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`String.isEmpty` is marginally faster (~0.00219ms vs ~0.00206ms, about 6%). This is such a trivially small amount that there's no reason to worry about which one you use from a performance perspective.

Practically speaking, you should generally use `String.isBlank` if you expect potentially whitespace strings (e.g. from user input that may be all whitespace), and `String.isEmpty` when checking fields from the database, which will never contain a string of just whitespace.

Comment: I haven't really tested it out, but would agree with such marginal difference, it mostly depends on what you want to validate -- blank vs. empty.

Comment: @JayantDas Yeah, a difference this small means about 0.00012ms per use, so you would need millions of uses to make a difference.

Comment: Haven't you mixed these two up?  `isBlank` is the one when you expect whitespace strings and not the other way around, and it must be the slower one since it needs to check characters and not just length.

Comment: @JakeCobb That's what I get for answering before coffee. I just realized i mixed up my variables in the benchmark I was using. One sec...

Answer (score 3):

Faster here is very broad to classify, as you will need lot of considerations to test that out. It depends on what is your use case and accordingly which method fits in best.

[`String.isBlank`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm) handles any string even with white space, whereas the same is not true for [`String.isEmpty`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm). So if you expect empty string (`''`) always, then using either of them should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

`String.isEmpty()` will be better. Assuming that you are not expecting strings containing just whitespace returning a `true` value. If you want it to also treat strings containing whitespace as empty use `String.isBlank()`

The difference between the two is very slight but the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_methods) specify what will be returned depending on input.